# Find inverse element of $1+2\alpha$ in $\mathbb{F}_9$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, modular-arithmetic, finite-fields

> Let $$\mathbb{F}_9 = \frac{\mathbb{F}_3[x]}{(x^2+1)}$$ and consider $\alpha = \bar{x}$. Compute $(1+2 \alpha)^{-1}$

I think I should use the extended Euclidean algorithm: so I divide $x^2 +1 $ by  $(1+2x)$:

$$x^2 + 1 = (1+2x)(2x+2)+2$$

$$(2x+2)(1+2x) + 2(x^2+1) = 1$$

Therefore, considering $\text{mod}(x^2+1) $, I have $$(2x+2)(1+2x) = 1\text{mod}(x^2+1)$$

and so $2x+2 = (1+2x)^{-1}$

Is it okay, or did I misunderstood something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$(2x+2)(2x+1)=2(x+1)(2x+1)=2(2x^2+3x+1).$
Since we are in $\mathbb{F}_3,$ then $3x=0$ and $4x^2=x^2$ so
$(2x+2)(2x+1)=2(2x^2+1)=4x^2+2=x^2+2=(x^2+1)+1,$
reducing modulo $(x^2+1)$ we get $1,$ so yeah, you are correct.

Comment: Thanks, now to check my result I should multiply $1+2x + (f)$ and $2x+2 + (f) $ and see if I get $1+(f)$

Comment: No, you haven't, your process was correct, I just checked by multiplying because you asked if it was ok.

Comment: my bad. yeah, that was what you verified :) thanks

Answer (score 2):

Your answer is correct.

Note that $\alpha^2=-1$, and the conjugate of $\alpha$ is $-\alpha$,

so $\dfrac1{1+2\alpha}=\dfrac1{1+2\alpha}\dfrac{1-2\alpha}{1-2\alpha}=\dfrac{1-2\alpha}{1-4\alpha^2}=\dfrac{1-2\alpha}{1-\alpha^2}=\dfrac{1-2\alpha}2=2^{-1}-\alpha=2+2\alpha$

in $\mathbb F_9$.

Comment: This is the way I’d do it. Why forget your high-school algebra, when it works perfectly well here?

Comment: I appreciate the vote of confidence, @Lubin!